# Node.js Promise reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm getting a reference error saying check is not defined when I call `check().then(function(employees)` towards the bottom of my code and I;m not sure why. This happens when I call `getAllEmployees()`;

```
var employees = [];
var departments = [];
var error = 0;
function initialize(){
    var fs = require("fs");


    fs.readFile("./data/employees.json", 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            error = 1;
        }
        employees = JSON.parse(data);
        //console.log(employees);
    });


    fs.readFile("./data/department.json", 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            error = 1;
        }
        departments = JSON.parse(data);
       // console.log(departments);
    });


    let check = function(){
        return new promise(function(resolve,reject){
            if (error === 0){
                resolve("Success");
            }
            else if(error === 1){
                reject("unable to read file");
            }
        })     
    };
}


function getAllEmployees(){

    check().then(function(employees){
        console.log(employees);
    }).catch(function(){
        console.log("No results returned");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `check` is not defined in the scope of `getAllEmployees` function, because you have defined `check` function as local function inside `initialize` function.

First weird thing:

```
function initialize(){
    var fs = require("fs");
```

Maybe it's best if you set all require modules at the top, not inside the function.

---

I did some modifications to your code, now you won't have that error:

```
var employees = [];
var departments = [];
var error = 0;
var fs = require("fs");

function initialize(){
    fs.readFile("./data/employees.json", 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            error = 1;
        }
        employees = JSON.parse(data);
        //console.log(employees);
    });


    fs.readFile("./data/department.json", 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err){
            error = 1;
        }
        departments = JSON.parse(data);
       // console.log(departments);
    });
}

function check() {
    return new promise(function(resolve,reject){
        if (error === 0){
            resolve("Success");
        }
        else if(error === 1){
           reject("unable to read file");
        }
    })     
};

function getAllEmployees(){
    initialize();
    check().then(function(employees){
        console.log(employees);
    }).catch(function(){
        console.log("No results returned");
    });
}
```

---

***Summary of changes I did:***

First, locate the main problem about you are asking, why are you getting `"check function is not found"`?. As I said in the beginning, `check` function was declared in the `initialize` scope function and `getAllEmployees` was declared outside so the main error is clear.

What I did: change `initialize` function to only get json data and set two global variables: `employees` and `departments`.
Move `check` function to outside of `initialize` scope, as a module function to check promises.

Change `getAllEmployees` function to first, call `initialize` (to get json data and set the global variables) and call `check` function.

There are best ways to manage promises as for example the way provide as @Rafael in his answer.

Comment: It works but printing the employees array results inside getAllEmployees results in an empty array

Comment: Maybe you have a different error due to what are you getting from json, maybe you should ask a new question with that problem

Comment: I will ask a new question. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

- You forgot to capitalize Promise
- Your code structure is terrible
- Wrap legacy node async code in Promises
- Defer error handling code to caller
- import native node libs at root level (make them consts too)

Here is the refactored version:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const read = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

function init() {
    var reads = ["employees.json", "department.json"]
                .map(file => read(`./data/${file}`, "utf8").then(JSON.parse));

    return Promise.all(reads)
           .then(([employees, departments]) => ({ employees, departments }));
}

init().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Great refactored version

Comment: I would suggest putting the `JSON.parse()` in the `myread()` function to make it more DRY.  And, in node version 8+, you can use `util.promisfy()` instead of manually promisifying it.  I would also suggest showing a `.catch()` to handle errors.

Comment: nah, I don't want to imply any specific use of `myread()`, keepin it generic. If I really wanted to be DRY, I could just `var load = ['path1.json', 'path2.json'].map(j => myread(j).then(JSON.parse));` which would incur a negligible runtime overhead.

Comment: I added the other suggestions though

Comment: Nice use of the spread syntax to clarify what's in [0] and [1] on the array.

Comment: that is array destructuring, spread is a bit different, thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

[The explicit construction is an antipattern](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern). If you have Node.js 8 you can use `promisify` or use bluebird version of with an older environment. With it you can rewrite your code in much cleaner way and handle the errors properly.

Also it make sense to say that [its a bad practice to throw(reject with) string](https://gist.github.com/jimmyjacobson/f98ffe22d3259fe1062d)

```
const {promisify} = require('util');

const fs = require('fs');
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);

Promise.all([
    readFileAsync("./data/employees.json", {encoding: 'utf8'}).then(x => JSON.parse(x)),
    readFileAsync("./data/department.json", {encoding: 'utf8'}).then(x => JSON.parse(x))
])
    .then(([employees, departments]) => {
        console.log(employees);
    })
    .catch(console.log)
```

Comment: FYI, `readFileAsync()` does not automatically parse the JSON data.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't do what the OP's code does without the `JSON.parse()`.  It looks simpler than it really can be.  Why don't you just edit and fix?

Comment: Well stackoverflow isn't about rewriting somebody else code. IMHO, it's about ideas. But... edited.

Comment: Your choice what kind of answers you want to supply, but complete answers that show everything required to solve the OP's problem are generally considered better answers which is why I commented.  FYI, `.then(x => JSON.parse(x))` can be `.then(JSON.parse)`.